# Importing FBX into blender moves meshes under armature instead of keeping groupings

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, maya, fbx

I'm using a workflow that goes from our art team who is using Maya to in-house Blender to Unity3d. If I import an fbx from our art team and import it into Unity3d, I see the proper hierarchy (parent with two children, one child is the mesh data, one child is the rig). However, if I import the fbx into Blender (3.3) into a blank collection, it splits the fbx out into 2 children only, 1 is the hierarchy, but it is entirely empty objects, and 1 is the armature, and underneath the armature is all the mesh data in a single list. Then if I export it again and import into unity, it loses the mesh hierarchy. Is there any way around this using this workflow (different blender version, 3rd party fbx, etc). I assume I can reparent everything, but we have a large number of fbxs. Here's an example of what happens: Unity vs Blender: [image: Unity] vs [image: Blender]

Thanks for any help!

I've tried different fbx versions and different settings in blender/unity.